# How to create an exact copy of file in c

Tags: c

I want to create an exact copy of a file(.bmp) in c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *str,*cptr;

    if((str=fopen("org.bmp","rb"))==NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Cannot read file\n");
        //return 1;
    }

    if((cptr=fopen("copy.bmp","wb"))==NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Cannot open output file\n");
        //return 1;
    }

    fseek(str, 0, SEEK_END);
    long size=ftell(str);
    printf("Size of FILE : %.2f MB \n",(float)size/1024/1024);
    char b[2];

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        fread(b,1,1,str);
        fwrite(b,1,1,cptr);
    }

    fseek(cptr, 0, SEEK_END);
    long csize=ftell(str);
    printf("Size of created FILE : %.2f MB \n",(float)csize/1024/1024);
    fclose(str);
    fclose(cptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Although it creates a file of the same size but windows throws an error while trying to view the newly created copy of bitmap.
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have moved the file pointer for the input file to the end of the file before you start reading it. You need to restore it to the beginning.

Change:

```
fseek(str, 0, SEEK_END);
long size=ftell(str);
```

to:

```
fseek(str, 0, SEEK_BEGIN);
long size=ftell(str);
fseek(str, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

Note that your code is devoid of error checking - if you had at least checked the result of `fread` then your mistake would have been immediately apparent. Take-home message: don't cut corners when it comes to error-checking - it will pay dividends later.

Comment: I general do error checking, i just got lazy there.Anyways thanks for the help.

Comment: How write the entire file by using a single call to fwrite other than looping through fread and fwrite ?

Comment: @RAZER: allocate a buffer that is the same size as the file. Or for larger files where this might be impractical, use a buffer of, say, 1024 chars, and read and write (up to) 1024 chars at a time.

Comment: It'll help if could give some examples.

Answer (score 3):

You need to seek back to the start of the original file because you are continually reading at the EOF and therefore not making a copy of the file contents, just whatever happens to be in your b[] array.

You are not checking the return codes of fread() and fwrite(). If you had been doing that you might have solved this problem from the return codes.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the size of the original file and the copy in bytes, it should tell you the issue.

This code reads a byte and writes a byte.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define KB 1024

int main()
{
    unsigned int ifd,ofd,rcnt;
    char buf[KB];

    ifd=open("orig.jpg",O_RDONLY);
    if(ifd==0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Cannot read file\n");
        //return 1;
    }

    ofd=open("copy.jpg",O_WRONLY|O_CREAT);
    if(ofd==0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Cannot open output file\n");
        //return 1;
    }

    while(rcnt=read(ifd,buf,KB))
        write(ofd,buf,rcnt);
}
```

~

Comment: How write the entire file by using a single call to fwrite other than looping through fread and fwrite ?

Comment: Seems like with fread/fwrite one can't get actual bytes read/written. You can migrate to read/write, check my edited solution. Modify KB accordingly to have required buffer.

Comment: To do in single shot you can get the file size using **stat()**, then allocating buffer as reqd.

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice function to copy files! Copy `char` by `char` is better than read the whole file because that result (if the file is to long) is a bufferoverflow!

```
double copy(char *input, char *output) {
    FILE *f_in = fopen(input, "r");
    FILE *f_out = fopen(output, "a");
    if (!f_in || !f_out) {
        fclose(f_in);
        fclose(f_out);
        return -1;
    }
    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(f_in)) != EOF)
        fputc(c, f_out);
    fclose(f_in);
    fseek(f_out, 0, SEEK_END);
    long size = ftell(f_out);
    fclose(f_out);
    return (double)(size / 1024 / 1024); // MB
}
```

This function returns the MB of the output file. If it wasn't successfully it return `0`.

Use this function like this:

```
double output;
if ((output = copy("What ever you want to copy", "Where ever it should be printed")) != -1)
    printf("Size of file: %lf MB.\n", output);
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: This will be very slow. Copying bigger numbers of bytes at once is usually much faster.

Answer (score 0):

I copped your first code and also used first solution just you need to add this code to your program :fseek(str, 0, SEEK_SET);and done your copy bitmap will be produce.